# How to check if a column exists in a csv file during sql server OpenRowset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I got a very tricky question and not sure if there is a way to get it work. 
Basically, I have user uploaded a csv file. The first row is header. I need to check if a column name does exists in this csv file. For example I want to know if that csv file has a StudentName column. How do I do that?

I tried to import the file to a temp table. Once I have it in a temp table, I can get everything I need.

```
select * into #temp 
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
               , 'Text; Database='+@folder+'; HDR=NO; IMEX=1;'
               ,'select top 1 * from ' + @filename)
```

But that does not work because openrowset cannot have variable in it. In order to make it work, I have to put this whole thing into a @sql variable then exec it.

However, that would not work either because if I do exec (@sql) I cannot use #temp because #temp will not be available after exec(@sql).

Any other way to get this work?

I hope to have some function or stored procedure like this: IsColumnExists(@directory, @filename, @colName)

Thanks.

Comment: You can use: ##Temp (global temporary table), @Temp (Table variable). The latter will require you to use sp_execute with an output parameter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.  I've never had the need to do this, but I can see  how useful it could be.  I tested this on SQL 2012.

```
--We'll do this dynamically.  Change these values for your scenario.
--If you want to make this into a stored proc, these next two variables would be the sp input params.
DECLARE @Folder NVARCHAR(256) = 'D:\'   --Or other folder
DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(128) = 'Test.csv'  --Or other file.

--Temp table.  This will ultimately hold the names of the columns from the OPENROWSET query.
CREATE TABLE #ColNames (name SYSNAME)

--Build tsql string...
DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT *
    INTO #Temp
    FROM OPENROWSET (           
        ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',   
        ''Text;Database=' + @Folder + ';HDR=YES'',   
        ''SELECT * FROM [' + @FileName + '] WHERE 1 = 2''  
    ) dt;

    SELECT name
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#Temp'')  
'
--...pass string to EXEC
INSERT INTO #ColNames
EXEC (@Tsql)

--Return a resultset of column names.
--Add additional logic to test for presence/absence of specific column.
SELECT *
FROM #ColNames

DROP TABLE #ColNames
```

Comment: That works great. The second part of the @Tsql resolved my issue nicely. Thanks!